# From where do I get FoxPro?

Tags: windows, foxpro, database

I want to use `Fox Pro`. The old DBMS. I have been searching for its download link but haven't found any.

Can anyone please help me with the download link.

Answer (score 2):

Successor language is [Visual Foxpro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vfoxpro/bb190225.aspx), which is still available from Microsoft.  You can download it with a MSDN subscription.

Comment: you call foxpro a language. And I am calling it a dbms software ! What is it ?

Comment: FoxPro is a DBMS with its own language.  If you just need to access the data in its files, you can probably find libraries for more modern languages, or ODBC drivers.  If you need the language, Visual FoxPro is probably your best bet.

Comment: It's an example of something that doesn't really exist that much any more, probably. Visual FoxPro is an object-oriented language with integrated GUI and report designer etc, and a native database that is a first-class citizen in the language itself. So all the data access that you often have to add an ORM layer for in Java or C# is built right in.

Answer (score 1):

Neither FoxPro nor Visual FoxPro can just be downloaded. They're not available for free, at least not legally.